# How to get request object in django xadmin

Tags: python, django

Trying to get the request object in `adminx.py` inside a class `exampleAdmin` or even better inside a class `exampleForm`.

I saw several example but non of them work for the xadmin backend. One example was to overwrite `get_form`, but it never triggers. Must have something to do with how xadmin is build. This is the usual example:

```
def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = super(EventAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
    form.request = request
    return form
```

Unfortunately this example does not work for xadmin and I cannot seem to find another way to get the request object.

Comment: What is xadmin or adminx?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class YourAdmin(object):
    form = YourForm

    def prepare_form(self):
        self.model_form = self.get_model_form()
        self.model_form.request = self.request
```

Then in your form method you can access `self.request`.